# nginx url rewrite mysite.com/blog => blog.mysite.com/blog

Tags: regex, django, nginx, url-rewriting

hello regex and nginx - friends,

I have searched the web for hours, this drives me crazy :-) I couldn't even find similar issues.
I want to rewrite mysite.com/blog -> blog.mysite.com/blog.

maybe I am totally wrong but right now I have:

```
  if ($host !~* ^(blog|subdomain)/blog$) {
       rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://blog.$host/$1 permanent;
 }
```

This works a little bit but not really. I get:
`http://blog.blog.mysite.com/blog` always 2 times blog. Why?

and could you please check my "IF" statement? I think it's incorrectly written, because what I really want to say is:
if URI does not begin with blog and ends with /blog than add 'blog.' to the beginning directly after http:// that it will look like http://blog.mysite.com/blog.

Thank you guys a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Right now you are trying to compare hostname to match url path.

```
location /blog {
  if($host !~* ^(blog.mysite.com)$) {
    rewrite ^/(.)$ $scheme://blog.$host/$1 permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: well this solution does not solve all my problems right now. i will post the solution as soon as i got it.

Comment: its still coming to be same?.

Answer (score 0):

so guys i have to answer my own question. 
forgive me, its not really an answer.
First things First, ... i have gave up on this one.

Why? 
Well, i thought it would be nice to power my forum blog and shop with pretty uris like
blog.mysite.com
shop.mysite.com
forum.mysite.com
the hole stuff is django + nginx(serving static files) + apache2 - driven.
right now my urls look like this: mysite.com/forum mysite.com/blog mysite.com/shop.
and i do not see a solution how i could change that.
if i manage todo a rewrite i would have another problem, because i would got uris similar to this one blog.mysite.com/blog which doesn't look very pretty either.
my hole django application is done with one apache VirtualHost and only one wsgi_handler.

So if i really wanted subdomains.

i should do it similar to this approach: [multiple-subdomains](http://www.devcomments.com/q526886/Problem-with-multiple-subdomains-conflict-Ubuntu-django-nginx)

And i thinks in meaning of SEO (search engine optimization) maybe multiple subdomains aren't really a good idea. maybe subdomains count not that much as subfolders in URLs.

So if none of you gives me a glory solution how real man do this, i will go to my A-Records blog shop forum and delete them. so i will just go with mysite.com/*

what do you guys think?
greetings sc